# JWPlayer 5 - How to add download link at the player

Tags: download, jwplayer

so this is the sript for the player

```
jwplayer("flvplayer").setup({
 file: "$direct_link",
 flashplayer: "$c->{site_url}/player/$name.swf",
 image: "$file->{video_img_url}",
 duration:"$file->{vid_length}",
 width: $file->{vid_width},
 height: $file->{vid_height},
 provider: 'http',
 modes: [ { type: "flash", src: "$c->{site_url}/player/$name.swf" },{ type: "html5", config:     {file:'$direct_link','provider':'http'} }, { type: "download" } ]  });
```

I want to add a download link button, like player on this website, example >> http://www.mp4upload.com/a6hxfn9hdxuy

Can you guys help me?

Thanks before :D

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1436999-example-adding-a-download-button

```
​<script>
jwplayer().addButton(
//This portion is what designates the graphic used for the button
   "/uploads/myButton.png",
//This portion determines the text that appears as a tooltip
   "Download Video", 
//This portion designates the functionality of the button itself
   function() {
//With the below code, we're grabbing the file that's currently playing
   window.location.href = jwplayer().getPlaylistItem()['file'];
 },
//And finally, here we set the unique ID of the button itself.
"download"
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this is for JW5. Here is a plugin you can use, save this file as download.js:

```
(function(jwplayer){

  var template = function(player, div, config) {

    var assets = {
        download: "http://www.longtailvideo.com/sites/default/files/download.png"
    }

    var goDownload = function() {
        var item = player.getPlaylistItem();
        if(item['downloadlink']) {
            document.location = item['downloadlink'];
        } else if(config.link) { 
            document.location = config.link;
        } else {
            document.location = item.file;
        }
    };

    function setup(evt) {
        player.getPlugin("dock").setButton(
            'downloadButton',
            goDownload,
            assets.download
        );
    };
    player.onReady(setup);

    this.resize = function(width, height) {};
  };

  jwplayer().registerPlugin('download', template);

})(jwplayer);
```