# Jw Player, give video link to Anchor

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

The code to add a download button to the player can be found in the following post:

- [JWPlayer 5 - How to add download link at the player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410651/jwplayer-5-how-to-add-download-link-at-the-player)

However, I want to add an anchor below the player, which will hold the link to the video. I tried several things but I can't figure it out.

For example, i have tried the following:

```
<a href="window.location.href = player.getPlaylistItem()['file']"
class="button">Download</a>
```

I have even tried to make it work with a button:

```
<button onclick="function()">Download</button>
```

But it still does not work.

I have added all my tested codes here: https://jsfiddle.net/au50sk8c/

I hope someone can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: You can give option outside the player, where user can download your file. thats better solution.

Comment: but u see the player get the link through POST method so it's not applicable in that case.

Comment: if i am correct understand your code then you will get file name or file id. in that case you can call download function with file/file name and user can download it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the link to the video adapt your script as follows:

```
let videoUrl = "the link to your video";
document.querySelector('#idOfLink').href = videoUrl;

//also adapt this line
playlist: [{"sources":[{"type": "video/mp4", "label": "HD", "file": videoUrl}]
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid question: what feature do you use that the HTML `<video>` can't do?